# How to connect HornetQ message broker with RESTful service JAX-RS Jersey

Tags: java, jms, jax-rs, activemq-classic, middleware

I have created a RESTful service using JAX-RS Jersey and deployed it on a tomcat 7 server.

Now I would like to use JMS. The request would be captured and directed to a message queue on a message broker and from there messages should be pushed towards the REST service and then the response would be redirected to the end user.

I am using Activemq. How can I integrate Activemq with a RESTful service?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want the REST service to put messages on the message queue and then have the messages processed in a REST service?

Comment: @Zagrev  I mean that Client(vendors ) will be sending the request (messages) that will be in Message Queue and then forwarded to the Restful service that will give some response in JSON/XML and then it will again sent back to Client as the response for the same message. My Rest Service is a separate entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webservice interface needs to offer two functions: `submit` and `poll`.

- The client calls `submit` which in turn sends the request as a JMS message on the incoming queue, and returns the message ID. `submit` returns after that.
- The request processing runs asynchronously. For example a message driven bean (MDB) listens on the incoming queue, processes the message, and puts the result on an outgoing  queue. It sets the **correlation ID** of the result message to the message ID of the incoming request. The correlation ID is required to connect the request and its result.
- The client calls the `poll` function with the message ID (as returned by `submit`) as an argument: `poll` checks the result queue using a JMS message selector on the correlation ID. It returns "not yet completed" or the result. The client possibly needs to call `poll` multiple times to get the result.

Notes:

- A JMS message selector is a filter (like a where clause in a database): It is required in this scenario to identify the result for a given request.
- Javadoc of [setJMSCorrelationID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: ya..i was on the same line. However, I am will ask more on this once I am come on this again. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Beryyllium Hi, I am unable to do this. Could you please give me more insight. If possible could you give me a sample example where one servlet where filter mechanism is there and resource class with Jersey. I am stuck and not getting any clue. Please help. Thanks